# How to define drools rule for list of string as POST method in POSTMAN

Tags: java, post, drools

```
public class QuestionnaireReq {

    private String questionId;
    private List<String> answerText;

    public String getQuestionId() {
        return questionId;
    }
    public void setQuestionId(String questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }

    public List<String> getAnswerText() {
        return answerText;
    }
    public void setAnswerText(List<String> answerText) {
        this.answerText = answerText;
    }

}
```

and drools file

rule "qustionRule_3"

```
when
questionnaireReq : QuestionnaireReq(questionId=="q2" && $answerText=="Web UI front-end");
questionnaireRes : QuestionnaireRes();
then
questionnaireRes.setNextQuestionId("q3");
end
```

and postman request here

```
{
    "questionId":"q3",
    "answerText":["Web UI front-end","Web Back-end"]

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to match any one item in `answerText` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to ask is how to update your rule to check that a value is *in* a list, since your original rule is trying to do an `==` which will never match since you're comparing a list to a string.

In this case you'll want to use the Drools `contains` operator, which verifies that a list contains a given element.

```
rule "qustionRule_3"
when
  questionnaireReq : QuestionnaireReq( questionId=="q2",
                                       answerText contains "Web UI front-end")
  questionnaireRes : QuestionnaireRes()
then
  questionnaireRes.setNextQuestionId("q3");
end
```

You can read more about the `contains` operator in the official Drools documentation, in the section called ["Supported operators in DRL pattern constraints"](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.33.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#drl-operators-ref_drl-rules).